# Group by field of an item of an array

Tags: elasticsearch

Here example documents:

```
{
  "_id": "doc_1",
  "play_count": 1,
  "meta": {
    "ancestors": [
      {"content_type": "Folder"},
      {"content_type": "SerieContainer",
        "_id": "super_doc_1"
      }
    ]
  }
}


{
  "_id": "doc_2",
  "play_count": 10,
  "meta": {
    "ancestors": [
      {"content_type": "Folder"},
      {"content_type": "SerieContainer",
        "_id": "super_doc_1"
      }
    ]
  }
}


{
  "_id": "doc_3",
  "play_count": 100,
  "meta": {
    "ancestors": [
      {"content_type": "Folder"},
      {"content_type": "SerieContainer",
        "_id": "super_doc_1"
      }
    ]
  }
}


{
  "_id": "doc_4",
  "play_count": 500,
  "meta": {
    "ancestors": [
      {"content_type": "Folder"},
      {"content_type": "SerieContainer",
        "_id": "super_doc_2"
      }
    ]
  }
}


{
  "_id": "doc_5",
  "play_count": 5,
  "meta": {
    "ancestors": [
      {"content_type": "Folder"},
      {"content_type": "SerieContainer",
        "_id": "super_doc_2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is it possible to group those documents by _id of items of ancestors whose "content_type" field is equal to "SerieContainer" and then get sum of "play_count" field of them?

For example:

```
super_doc_1: 111 (doc_1, doc_2, doc_3)
super_doc_2: 505 (doc_4, doc_5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `ancestors` is type of [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) so that there is an association. So you could have your `mapping` something as follows. I've just given for the `array` type:

```
"ancestors": {
          "type": "nested",
          "include_in_parent": true, 
          "properties": {
            "content_type": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "_id": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
```

And then maybe you could have your `aggs` query something like this in order to `groupby` using the id and content type.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "ancestors": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "item.meta.ancestors"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "item.meta.ancestors.id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "content_type": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "item.meta.tags.content_type"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hence you could have a `pattern` in order to match your content type or id field to filter. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806391/elasticsearch-filtering-aggregations-from-array-field) could come in handy. Hope it helps!