# How to filter top terms aggregation in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql-aggregation, nosql

I have `orders` documents like this:

```
{
   "customer":{
      "id":1,
      "Name":"Foobar"
   },
   "products":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Television",
         "category": 11
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Smartphone",
         "category": 12
      }
   ]
}
```

And I am performing a `top_terms_aggregation` in order to know the products best sellers. To do it globally, I use:

```
{
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{
      "products":{
         "nested":{
            "path":"products"
         },
         "aggs":{
            "top_terms_aggregation":{
               "terms":{
                  "field":"products.id",
                  "size":10
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But, how would I filter the products given a `category_id`? I tried adding this filter:

```
  "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "products.category":11
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

But this filters the orders itself that has **some** product with the given category, and the aggregation gets corrupted.

I want to get the best sellers products that **belongs** to a given category.

Comment: Try this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806391/elasticsearch-filtering-aggregations-from-array-field

Comment: Wont solve my problem: I must keep the `nested-path` criteria and filter through documents that fits into an integer category id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this way:

```
{
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{
      "products":{
         "nested":{
            "path":"products"
         },
         "aggs":{
            "first_filter":{
               "filter":{
                  "term":{
                     "products.category":11
                  }
               },
               "aggs":{
                  "top_terms_aggregation":{
                     "terms":{
                        "field":"products.id",
                        "size":10
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Must be this exact sequence of `aggs` or "stranger things" happens.

Answer (score 2):

You  may use [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html)

```
GET _search
{
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{
      "products":{
         "nested":{
            "path":"products"
         },
         "filter": {
           "term": {
             "category": 11
           }
         }, 
         "aggs":{
            "top_terms_aggregation":{
               "terms":{
                  "field":"products.id",
                  "size":10
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't works because it falls into `Found two aggregation type definitions in [products]: [nested] and [filter]`. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yea.. You are right. I just typed this query in SO editor, hence missed this issue. Glad you are able to solve it yourself based on the answer.